# Java while(input.hasnextline) loop not exiting?

Tags: java, file, io

SO I'm supposed to determine the number of lines in a text file (a 100 lines containg numbers) and then create an array with the the number of lines, but the first while loop used to find out the number of lines in the text file never exits. The second loop which is the exacts same one works just fine. Please help me out!

```
static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("seriesOfNumbers.txt"); //file instance                
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file); //Scanner
    int M =0 ;
    while (input.hasNextLine() && !input.equals(null))// ** Loop never exits, tried almost everything
    {
        k++;
    }
    double[] numberArray = new double[k];
    int V = 0;
    while (input.hasNextLine())// When I exit the first loop this one exits just fine
    {
        numberArray[j] = (double) input.nextInt();
        j++;
    }
```

Comment: You never advance the Scanner, you should call one of its `.next*` methods.

Comment: be careful with `input.equals(null)`. if `input` is really `null`, you will get `NullPointerException`. use `input != null` instead

Comment: @user3454973 If an answer has solved your question, then please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never consuming your input in the first loop, do that with `input.nextLine()`.

You are now looping until `input.hasNextLine()` becomes false, but that never happens, because you do not consume the input.

Answer (score 0):

Use input.next() to move to next line. In While condition you are checking the has next line and not null. Thats y it is in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In this below code,
this is initialising

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(file); //Scanner
```

This is reading

```
int M =0 ;
while (input.hasNextLine() && !input.equals(null))
{
    input.nextLine();  // Use this to advance the lines from scanner
    k++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could use FileUtils class from apache.commons.io project to do the trick.

```
static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("..."));
```

Now, if you really need the numberArray for some other computation, you can

```
    double[] d = new double[lines.size()];
```

Or you can use the Collection to iterate

```
    for (String line : lines) {
        double n = Double.parseDouble(line);
```

To use FileUtils, take a look  at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

But, iof all that you want is to know what is wrong with your code, you should call the method `Scanner.nextLine()` inside your first while loop.

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop the infinite looping of the while loop even after consuming the required inputs, we can use a `break` statement.

Here is an example,

```
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] arr = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            long[] ar = new long[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                ar[i] = Long.parseLong(arr[i]);
            }
            long result = sum(ar);
            System.out.println(result);
            break;
        }
```